# await layer.LoadAsync(); invalid response | ArcGIS DevLab; Load an item from ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

---

So I am doing some excercises in the DevLab from the ArcGIS developer platform.
I did an excercise in which you load a layer from the ArcGIS Online portal. Their example code is the following (it works like a charm);

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping;
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Portal;

namespace LoadAnItemFromArcGISOnline
{
/// <summary>
/// Provides map data to an application
/// </summary>
public class MapViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MapViewModel()
    {
        InitializeMap();
    }

    private Map _map = new Map(Basemap.CreateTopographic());

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the map
    /// </summary>
    public Map Map
    {
        get { return _map; }
        set { _map = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="MapViewModel.PropertyChanged" /> event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that has changed</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var propertyChangedHandler = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChangedHandler != null)
            propertyChangedHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private async void InitializeMap()
    {
        // Create a portal
        ArcGISPortal portal = await ArcGISPortal.CreateAsync();

        // Hold a portal item ID
        String portalItemId = "883cedb8c9fe4524b64d47666ed234a7";

        // Create the portal item
        PortalItem portalItem = await PortalItem.CreateAsync(portal, portalItemId);

        // Create the layer
        FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(portalItem, 0);

        // Ensure the layer is loaded
        await layer.LoadAsync();

        // Create the map with updated basemap and initial viewpoint
        this.Map = new Map(Basemap.CreateTopographic()) { InitialViewpoint = new Viewpoint(layer.FullExtent) };

        // Add the layer to the map
        this.Map.OperationalLayers.Add(layer);
    }


}
}
```

However, I wanted to try using a different layer. The layer I tried it with is a public layer created by the dutch government. It is a layer showing the heights of the netherlands. http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=4feca304f23847feae20eec8fec76fd8

So I simply replaced the ID of the tutorial with the ID from the Dutch layer and it gives me an error with the await layer.LoadAsync();

It sais the following: 
`Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: 'Invalid response'`

It does show a map with an esri basemap with a global extent. but the app is none responsive.

The entire excercise is done in Visual studio with ArcGIS runtime sdk for .net extension.

---

So what I'm thinking is that the dutch layer has a different coordinate system or maybe the layer has a maximum scale, or maybe the issue is that the data is raster. Does anyone has a tip/ know how to fix it, so that I can display this layer and maybe eventually more dutch layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Portal items` can contain multiple different types of content. Where in the example the item contains a `Feature Service` (item represents a service endpoint that has trailhead features) and provides metadata to describe the content based on the common portal item metadata model.

[image]

The second item contains a [webmap](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/what-is-web-map.htm). Webmaps (or maps) are items that contain the full map definition including `Basemaps` and `Operational layers`. Compared to the item that only contains a single layer, maps can be describe/author the whole map.

[image]

So the reason why your code doesn't work is that you try to create a `Feature Layer` from `Map`. You can use `PortalItemType` enum to check which type the item is.

```
        if (portalItem.Type == PortalItemType.FeatureService)
        {
            // it's a feature service
            // Create the layer
            FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(portalItem, 0);
            // Ensure the layer is loaded
            await layer.LoadAsync();
            // Create the map with updated basemap and initial viewpoint
            Map = new Map(Basemap.CreateTopographic()) { InitialViewpoint = new Viewpoint(layer.FullExtent) };
            Map.OperationalLayers.Add(layer);
        }
        if (portalItem.Type == PortalItemType.WebMap)
        {
            // Create map from a map definition
            Map = new Map(portalItem);
        }
```